# RWD Default theme – configurable product options change prices on upsell products

Tags: product, configurable-product, price, javascript, rwd-theme

I have a configurable Product in Magento, the theme is based on the rwd default, so it has all it's javascript included.

This configurable Product changes its price based on the selected option. That's fine but it also changes the price of the other configurable UPSELL products below. Why?

There is some javascript firing and i can't find anything where this is in and this makes absolutely no sense for me. I have configurable products as upsells below, with a "staring from ...$" prefix and the price should remain the same.

Anyone knows where this javascript is hiding?